# Shifting an array to the right

Tags: c++, arrays

I'm generating an array of random integers and trying to shift the values one to the right and replace the first element with the former last element.

The output is not ordered, and the final element is a randomly generated integer.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;


   void shift(int values[], int size) {
    int temp;
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {    
        temp = values[size - 1];
        values[i] = values[i + 1];
        values[0] = temp;
        cout << values[i] << setw(4);
    }
    cout << endl;
}
int main()
{
    cout << "Random 10 index array" << endl;
    const int CAP = 10;
    int numbers[CAP];

    srand(time(0));
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < CAP; i++) {
        int rng = rand() % 100 + 1;
        numbers[i] = rng;
        cout << numbers[i] << setw(4);

    }
    cout << "shifting all elements to the right: " << endl;
shift(numbers, CAP);

    cout << endl;
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

I tried using `i < size - 1`, but I got 9 out of the 10 numbers I needed.

Comment: [Your rubber duck wants to talk to you](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging). According to your rubber duck, the last element of your array should be moved to the first element just once, as part of this rotation. This is self evident, andyour rubber duck wants to know how you expect that to work, when the code to do so will be executed on every loop iteration, instead of just once. Your code does not make any sense at all, to your rubber duck, it seems.

Comment: Am I missing something, where is the call to shift.

Comment: `std::deque` is a better choice than an array for this application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the offending code:

```
        temp = values[size - 1];
```

This statement does not use the loop variable. Why is it sitting in the loop? This assignment will keep happening `size-1` times.

```
        values[i] = values[i + 1];
```

Your loop invariant is `i <size`, yet you try to access `i+1`. That's just asking for trouble :). This is why you don't get garbage values when you use `i < size-1`.

```
        values[0] = temp;
```

Again, this doesn't use the loop variable. It doesn't belong in the loop. You just keep setting `values[0]`over and over again.

Here's a solution that works, using two temp variables:

```
void shift(int values[], int size) {
  7     int temp = values[size-1], temp1;
  8     for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) { 
  9         temp1 = values[i];
 10         values[i] = temp;
 11         temp = temp1;
 12         cout << values[i] << setw(4);
 13     }
 14     cout << endl;
 15 }
```

Comment: I appreciate the help and more so, the explanation.

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried

> If you want a circular shift of the elements:
>
> std::rotate(&arr[0], &arr[1](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/rotate), &arr[10]); ... will do the trick. You'll
>   need to #include the algorithm header.

[Optimal way to perform a shift operation on an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1903190/optimal-way-to-perform-a-shift-operation-on-an-array)

Edit: As pointed out, std::rotate rotates left if used directly. [Here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/rotate) is an example doing rotate right on a vector with some change:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> v{2, 4, 2, 0, 5, 10, 7, 3, 7, 1}; 

    // simple rotation to the right
    std::rotate(v.rbegin(), v.rbegin() + 1, v.rend());

    std::cout << "simple rotate right : ";
    for (int n: v)
        std::cout << n << ' ';
    std::cout << '\n';

}
```

Output:

```
simple rotate right : 1 2 4 2 0 5 10 7 3 7
```

Comment: I'm afraid the rotate function only works to rotate things to the left.

Answer (score 0):

Another soution would be to copy the end of the array to the beginning of a temporary array and copy the beginning to the end of the temporary. Here is an exapmle with `std::vector`.

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
    
vector<int> shiftRight(vector<int> &A, int K) 
{
    if (A.size() <= 1) // No need to rotate if the array is smaller than 2 elements
        return A;

    K %= A.size(); // ensure K is less than size.
    
    vector<int> S(A.size());
    
    std::copy(A.cend() - K, A.cend() , S.begin());
    std::copy(A.cbegin(), A.cend() - K, S.begin() + K);

    return S;
}
```

It can be also implemented with `memcpy` which will be faster for big arrays.

```
#include <cstring>

void shiftRight(int *A, int size, int K) 
{
    if (size <= 1) // No need to rotate if the array is smaller than 2 elements
        return;

    K %= size; // ensure K is less than size.
    
    int *temp = new int[size];
    
    memcpy(temp, A + (size - K), K*sizeof(int));
    memcpy(temp + K, A, (size - K)*sizeof(int));

    memcpy(A, temp, size*sizeof(int)); // copy back to the original array
    delete [] temp;
}
```